# Ngnix + Gunicorn + Flask: How to figure out the real base URL

Tags: python, nginx, dns, flask, gunicorn

I have Ngnix/Gunicorn/Flask setup as described in [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/). In my Python/Flask code, I need to determine what domain/host the request was sent to. So if the request is for http://example.com/myapp, I need to be able find "example.com" dynamically while the request is being processed so I can include it in the response.

I should be able to add a DNS record for a new domain to point to the same server and still be able to find the new domain in the Python code without having to change anything on the server itself. I've tried the various normal ways of figuring out the base URL, such as request.url_root, but they just show the local proxy address (127.0.0.1:8000). Using relative paths instead in this case is not an option, because the protocol I am implementing requires an absolute URL path in the response.

Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you should define   SERVER_NAME variable in flask config: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/

After that domain name should be accessible by  `request.url_root`  or `request.headers['Host']`

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding what you are suggesting, I think that would require hard-coding a domain name on the server itself. This would mean that the server itself would need to know the domain name being used ahead of time, I would like to dynamically determine it from the request.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the line

```
include uwsgi_params;
```

in your nginx config.
[uwsgi_params file](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/uwsgi_params)

Comment: @TomSawyer please provide your full config